# How to pass variable to javascript function from <liferay-ui> tag?

Tags: liferay-6

I have wirtten following code but it does not gets executed

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>                   
<liferay-ui:input-checkbox param="<%=String.valueOf(item1.getUserId()) %>" formName="frmAllCompanyUserPanelDisplay" onClick="callAddEntry('String.valueOf(item1.getUserId())')" id="<%=String.valueOf(item1.getUserId()) %>"/>
</liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>

<script type="text/javascript">
function callAddEntry(Hello) {
alert("Hello " + Hello);
}
</script>
```

It gives me same output 'String.valueOf(item1.getUserId())' rather then fetching id dynamically, but when i use normal input checkbox every line of code executed fine? why?

can anyone help me out in solving this javascript problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try following one.. need to use expression in java script function as follows

callAddEntry('<%=String.valueOf(item1.getUserId())%>')

More abut liferay have look into to [www.liferaysavvy.com](http://www.liferaysavvy.com)

```
<liferay-ui:input-checkbox param="<%=String.valueOf(item1.getUserId()) %>" 
formName="frmAllCompanyUserPanelDisplay" onClick="callAddEntry('<%=String.valueOf(item1.getUserId())%>')" 
id="<%=String.valueOf(item1.getUserId()) %>"/>
```